# How do I get a facebook users' uploaded video data using Koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am trying to use Koala to access users uploaded videos. However when I try to get the details for a specific video the result I get is `false`.
My code is:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new  
result = @graph.get_object("video_id")
```

The value in result is always `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting the video ID from? Is the user whose access token you're using able to see the video?
'false' almost always means privacy checks failed, most commonly because the user who owns the content has disabled all platform apps from accessing their data, the content is on a page that the viewer isn't able to see, or the content owner has blocked the user

Comment: I am testing it using my own facebook account so nothing is blocked and i am using a video on my account and when i try to get its details using the facebook graphAPI test page it works.

Comment: So you get false from your app, but do get the details from the Graph API Explorer? Have the two access tokens got the same permissions? make a call to /me/permissions to check - you may have granted the Graph API Explorer some extra permissions that your own app isn't requesting

Comment: you were right my app didnt ask for permission for the user videos. I did ask for it for the graph API but not in the app itself. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can get the false from the graph api because of not mentioning the video permissions while authenticating the user to application.
I also got the same problem, but was resolved by including the "user_videos" in the list of permissions to get from user account.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/